# Fly fishing leaders braided

Tags: fishing, fly-fishing

Since braided line floats and mono sinks slowly; do they sell a tapered leader braided line?

This is my first-year fly fishing - so I may not know enough.  My current setup is a #8 rod with a braided loop going to the fly line.  I then have a tapered leader 9' - 10lb Rio tapered leader and a 3' - 10lb fluorocarbon tippet - for steelhead.

I would like to change the leader to braided and use a 6-8lb tippet for bass.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by braided line you mean something like spider-wire or power-pro, they wouldn't have the backbone to turn over a fly - especially something you are likely to throw for bass.

Most bass plugs are fairly large and they float - so the leader/tippet doesn't really have to float. It could even be argued that you're better off with it NOT sitting on the surface where it will cast a shadow and be more visible from below. Mono/fluorocarbon virtually disappears below the surface.

IF you are using a sinking bass fly - say like a leech, you don't want the leader to float anyway.

HOWEVER if you are dead set on your leader floating you could always apply something like Gink fly floatant to the leader - OR fall back on the old standby - nose oil.